# sshpass like ssh-agent or vice versa

Tags: ssh-agent

I like to hold ssh logins for the runtime of a script. For public key authentication, `ssh-agent` can be used, allowing me to enter the key passphrase once when the script is started. However, that doesn't work for interactive password logins. For those, `sshpass` can be used to provide a password, but it does not ask for the password (that must then be given on command line for example) nor does it provide multiple logins.

Can one of those tools or some other one provide an secure interactive password  prompt and a session serving this password to multiple `ssh` runs?